# How can I concatenate column B contents if the cell under autofilter identifier is blank?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using autofilter to look up a criteria in column A in Sheet1 and return the corresponding value from column B in a table, however I want to be able to make it concatenate if column B contents are in two cells. Column A is blank under the identifier in cases like this.

```
Sub ReturnTIResults()

Dim r As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

With Worksheets("Sheet1") ' reference results sheet
    If IsEmpty(.Range("A1")) Then .Range("A1").Value = "dummy header" 
    ' if A1 is empty, put a "dummy" header to make AutoFilter work properly

    .AutoFilterMode = False
    With .Range("B1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)).Offset(, -1) 'reference referenced sheet column A range from row 1 down to column B last not empty cell
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Formula = "=R[-1]C" ' fill referenced range blank cells with the same value as the not empty cell above
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=TI"
        On Error Resume Next
        Set r = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1,1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not r Is Nothing Then r.Copy Worksheets("Search Results").Range("B7")
        .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas).ClearContents ' clear cell with formulas
        If .Range("A1").Value = "dummy header" Then 
.Range("A1").ClearContents ' remove any "dummy" header
    End With
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7bfb.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested, I basically just inserted some code within your `If` branch.

Few things to note:

- `Application.Transpose` (used below to convert 2-d array to 1-d array) can only handle arrays of length ~65.5k. So if you have more filtered items than that, not all of them may get concatenated.
- Cells have a character limit of ~32.8k I think. If the result of your concatenation violates this limit, you may get an error when trying to assign the result.

But other than that, should work fine. Also, both of your `Application.ScreenUpdating` assignments seem to be `True`. You might want to look into that.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ReturnTIResults()

    Dim r As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    With Worksheets("Sheet1") ' reference results sheet
            If IsEmpty(.Range("A1")) Then .Range("A1").Value = "dummy header"
            ' if A1 is empty, put a "dummy" header to make AutoFilter work properly

            .AutoFilterMode = False
            With .Range("B1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)).Offset(, -1) 'reference referenced sheet column A range from row 1 down to column B last not empty cell
                .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Formula = "=R[-1]C" ' fill referenced range blank cells with the same value as the not empty cell above
                .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=TI"
                On Error Resume Next
                Set r = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                On Error GoTo 0
                If Not r Is Nothing Then
                    If r.Rows.Count > 1 Then
                        Dim toConcatenate As Variant
                        toConcatenate = Application.Transpose(r.Value2)
                        toConcatenate = VBA.Strings.Join(toConcatenate, ", ") ' <-- Change to whatever delimiter you want
                        Worksheets("Search Results").Range("B7").Value2 = toConcatenate
                    Else
                        Worksheets("Search Results").Range("B7").Value2 = r.Value2
                    End If
                End If
                .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

                .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas).ClearContents ' clear cell with formulas
                If .Range("A1").Value = "dummy header" Then .Range("A1").ClearContents ' remove any "dummy" header
            End With
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: @Noob I don't know what you mean by result, I can't see your sheet. Try stepping through the code with `F8`